# Should I practice at home or practice along with job in this company?

Tags: career-development, job-offer, new-job, job-change, work-experience

I'm B. Tech fresher. There’s a small product based **startup** company in Noida, India. I got a job for a small salary (which doesn’t matter to me till I become experienced). Here I have to write some **backend** of their website using PHP and MySQL, fix issues and maintain it. Now, my aim is to become a **Web Developer**. But I don’t have full experience and mastered skills right now to join a company that gives me a Web Developer post. I want to work with **HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, MySQL and other new important Web technologies** mostly. But this startup has mostly work related to backend only for me.

So I’m really confused whether I should join it because I've **2 issues**:
1. I'm aged 24 and still I haven't started earning anything. I've to pay rents and eat with my parents money. (I think I would be late if I don't start work now)
2. Practicing the skills for a job that matches with my wish, i.e., Web technologies. (There are 2 ways: Either sit home and practice or join this startup and practice things on **Sundays and 1-2 hours** daily after work)

I’ve got the offer letter and I’ve to reply them within 2 days. There’s very little chance of getting any other job of my choice at present in next 1-2 months as I lack perfect skills and companies in this area are not looking for freshers at this time (I'm 2 months late).

So should I join it or sit home and develop skills by practicing? Also, I’m ready to join this company for the backend work but again I’m afraid that I won’t be in touch with HTML CSS JS much. So in future, if I want to switch the job to a Web Developer, the experience of this product based company won’t be counted (I think so). So what would be the best way to ultimately do that would help me in near future in pursuing the career I want (**I’m satisfied with the salary they’re giving during probationary period but not fully satisfied with the post**)?

Comment: We cannot tell you what to do, this is a personal decision.

Comment: But still you could tell what would be better?

Comment: @VikasKumar Unfortunately these kind of questions are not on-topic to the stackexchange network. This is not an open forum where you can poll users on their opinions, but rather a resource where every question with a definitive answer, that is not opinion based, can and *should* be posted so that it can be found by others with the same question now or at some point in the future. To keep such a system clean and true to its purpose, posts asking for the communities opinion are deemed off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're a burden to your parents you should take the job. The experience is still usable in applying for work in the future. A lot more useful than saying you weren't working for that period. At 24 years old you should try and stand on your own feet as much as possible. Both for the sake of your parents and for your own self-confidence and life experience.

As far as practicing goes, I think you should do both, home study and at work if you get the chance. Focus as much as you can until you can get the job you want. Use everything you can, this is you investing in your own future.